# Ambiguous output redirect on solaris

Tags: java, redirect, logging, solaris, tee

I'm running Java program on solaris and want to redirect both standout and standerr to a log file while still keeping them in the console.

Here's the command I use:

```
Java -jar MyProgram.jar 2>&1 | tee build.log
```

However, it gives me the following error:

> Ambiguous output redirect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use ksh or bash, (t)csh doesn't support this syntax (and possibly not even the functionality)